# How to fix inconsistent migration history after cloning application from GitHub

Tags: python, django, sqlite, github, django-models

I am using the book 'Django for Beginners' to learn Django.
I cloned a repository from GitHub containing code for a website that simply allows users to create an account, log in and log out.

This is the repository:
https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforbeginners/tree/master/ch10-bootstrap

My goal is to use this website, be able to create an account and log in and log out with it.

I entered the folder and ran these commands in the terminal:

```
pipenv shell
pipenv install
python manage.py runserver
```

This was the output in the terminal:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 05, 2020 - 12:58:48
Django version 3.1, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

When I tried to create an account in the website, it gave the following error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signup/

no such table: accounts_customuser
```

To fix this I tried running the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

It was successful and gave this output:

```
No changes detected
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

However, when I try to create an account, it still gives the same error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signup/

no such table: accounts_customuser
```

There wasn't a migrations folder in the accounts applications so I migrated just the accounts application:

```
python manage.py makemigrations accounts
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model CustomUser
```

`python manage.py migrate accounts` raised an error:

```
python manage.py migrate accounts
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before 
its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors and how I should fix them.

This is the structure of my accounts application:

```
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

This is the code inside `0001_initial.py` :

```
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-10-05 13:01

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('age', models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Thank you very much for your help!